# Force Mail.app to show manual configuration options

Tags: mail.app, email, imap

Now that Outlook.com supports IMAP email I'd like to set up Mail.app (on OS X 10.7.5) to use it rather than POP for that account. I have it set up on my Windows and Android machines, so I know it works.

The issue is that Mail's auto configuration only detects the POP servers when I try to add a new account, and there are no manual configuration options to set up the IMAP details. Is there any way to add an account and show the necessary configuration options?

Comment: Do you set it up as an "other" type mail account? That should give you the option.

Comment: Nevermind I just realized you're not talking about iOS. Duhh sorry.

Comment: Try leaving password blank when you first enter info. Worked on 10.7.8 at least.

Comment: Hmm, Mail appears to remember the password despite the account having been removed and the computer restarted. If I leave the password blank it connects anyway which seems... wrong.

Comment: looks like you have a solution below for that now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr - Enter an *incorrect* password when setting up the account for the first time**

---

1. Open **Mail** → **Accounts…**.
2. Click the **+** to add an account.

   [image]
3. Select **Add Other Mail Account…** and click Continue.

   [image]
4. When the password is *required*, enter an **incorrect** password.

   [image]
5. It will request that the account be configured manually.

   [image]
6. Follow the instructions to add your mail configuration.

   [image]

Comment: This isn't what I'm getting. When I leave the password blank it connects to the POP server anyway. That seems wrong... The account was previously set up as a POP account in mail, before I deleted it to reconfigure. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @velvetkevorkian Instead of leaving it blank, try entering a random *incorrect* password.

Comment: Ah, that seems to do the trick. How intuitive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note: Possibly only relevant in Lion, Mail.app v.5.3
Turns out it's bypassable if you hold alt down. The "Create" button then changes to "Continue".

Not entirely on-topic protip: alt often changes the behavior of buttons to allow "power-users" to actually get things done which lusers probably shouldn't be bothered with. Try it on some menubar-items, e.g. the volume.